# Instantiate type with string parameter to constructor dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
if (FileType == typeof(ScanUploadFile))
{
    files.Add(new ScanUploadFile(filePath));
}
if (FileType == typeof(FaxFile))
{
    files.Add(new FaxFile(filePath));
}
if (FileType == typeof(BulkScanFile))
{
    files.Add(new BulkScanFile(filePath));
}
if (FileType == typeof(SpecialCategoryFile))
{
    files.Add(new SpecialCategoryFile(filePath));
}
```

How can I write it without the IF statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the constructor, you could use:

```
 Activator.CreateInstance(FileType, new string[] {filePath});
```

`Activator` is defined in the `System` library.

Comment: Goog one, I forgot that `CreateInstance` has an overload with parameters

Comment: I used it in an object mapping library once. :)

Comment: I used it too, but for my latest project I wanted to check whether the type actually has the constructor I need. That's the downside of using `CreateInstance` - you're kinda hoping that the correct constructor exists. In some cases you can't know for sure and all of a sudden you're doing something like "exception programming", which is bad.

Comment: @Dyppl, that's very true. If in the example above, FileType represented a type that didn't support the constructor with a string, then this approach could get messy.

Answer (score -1):

Use `GetConstructors` method of the `Type` object and chose the one with single parameter of type string, then invoke it.

Like so:

```
private ConstructorInfo GetStringConstructor(Type type)
{
    return (from ctor in type.GetConstructors()
            let pars = ctor.GetParameters()
            where pars.Length == 1 && pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(string)
            select ctor).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Use it like so:

```
var ctor = GetStringConstructor(typeof(Test));
if (ctor != null)
    files.Add(ctor.Invoke(new string[] {filePath}));
```

I made a separate method for extracting the constructor, but if you only intend to use it for actually creating an instance, you can refactor it all in one method that takes `string` and `Type` parameters. Pay some attention to proper error handling though.

**However**, I would consider [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) here instead of just diving in reflection right away. I can't know if it better suits your needs, but it seems like it probably does.

**EDIT:** I admit that the `CreateInstance` is nicer, but my method has the advantage of more control and better error handling.

Comment: I have the reflection working - thanks.  If I use the Factory pattern, wouldn't I just be moving the IF statements into the factory?  I'm thinking the factory would be something like FileFactory with a method called GetFile(Type fileType, string filePath) and the IF statement from my question.

Comment: @Anthony: yes, but then the switch (or ifs) will only be in one place (creation method). It's not such a big deal when you only have to change it once to add new type. Also, reflection is not cheap. I'm not saying that you have to optimize something like this prematurely, but reflection isn't more readable either, and instantation with ifs will give you errors in compile-time rather than run-time if something goes wrong (no suitable constructor found). The bottom line is, even if you use reflection in the creation method, you really should encapsulate it in something factory-like.